# Retornar dados do Jquery dentro do Input

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho o seguinte HTML

```
<select id="id_cliente">
    <option value="1">CLIENTE 1</option>
    <option value="2">CLIENTE 2</option>
    <option value="3">CLIENTE 3</option>
</select>
```

Possuo o seguinte jQuery:

```
$("#id_cliente").change(function(){
    var id_cliente = $("#id_cliente").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contrato/buscar_cliente",
        data: {id_cliente:id_cliente},
        success: function(data){
            $("#nome").data[nome];
            $("#telefone").data[telefone];
            $("#email").data[email];
            alert(data);
        }   
    });     
});
```

E a função de buscar o cliente:

```
public function buscar_cliente(){
    $this->db->where("id_cliente", $_POST['id_cliente']);
    print_r($this->db->get("clientes")->row());
}
```

Sei que da forma que eu fiz, não funciona... A minha pergunta é:

Como eu faço para que eu consiga exibir os dados do retorno, dentro de um input?
Exemplo: Irá me retornar: Nome, Telefone, Email...

```
<input type="text" id="nome" value="">
<input type="text" id="telefone" value="">
<input type="text" id="email" value="">
```

Comment: Qual a saída de console.log(data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#nome").data[nome];
$("#telefone").data[telefone];
$("#email").data[email];
```

substitua por:

```
$("#nome").val(data.nome);
$("#telefone").val(data.telefone);
$("#email").val(data.email);
```

O código pode variar de acordo com a formatação do qual vc retornou os dados no ajax.

Comment: Não deu certo dessa forma... Mas eu retornei de outra forma, o retorno vem via array, mas usei agora o json_encode para retornar e no jquery usei data = JSON.parse(data);, assim dá certo

Comment: Show @AndréBaill espero ter ajudado. abç

Answer (score 1):

Creio que se você fizer algo do tipo `$("#nome").val(data[nome]);` funciona, mas não sei ao certo como é o retorno da sua função.